# Merging 2 Binary Search Trees via Insertion

Tags: java, insert, merge, binary-search-tree

I'm currently implementing a Binary Search Tree and got stuck at merging it with another.
So far I've got:

- head: returns node with smallest node
- tail: returns tree w/o smallest node
- insert(value): conventional insert-method

Since I'm getting a StackOverflowError, I think it's best to provide all methods, instead of just the merge one. I'm pretty sure the error is somehow due to the amount of recursive calls.

I'd appreciate any help! TYVM.

```
public BinaryTree insert(int newValue) {
    if (newValue < value) {
        if (left == null) {
            return new BinaryTree(value, new BinaryTree(newValue), right);
        } else {
            return new BinaryTree(value, left.insert(newValue), right);
        }
    } else if (newValue > value) {
        if (right == null) {
            return new BinaryTree(value, left, new BinaryTree(newValue));
        } else {
            return new BinaryTree(value, left, right.insert(newValue));
        }
    }
    return this;
}

public int head() {
    if (left != null) {
        return left.head();
    }
    return value;
}

public BinaryTree tail() {
    if (left != null) {
        return new BinaryTree(value, left.tail(), right);
    } else {
        return new BinaryTree(value, left, right.tail());
    }
```

}

```
public BinaryTree merge(BinaryTree other) {
    if (other != null) {
        insert(other.head()merge(other.tail()));
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public BinaryTree merge(BinaryTree other) {
    if (other != null) {
        return insert(other.head()).merge(other.tail());
    }
    return this;
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Get the tail of a tree.
 * @return the tree without the smallest value.
 */
public BinaryTree tail() {
    if (left != null) {
        return new BinaryTree(value, left.tail(), right);
    }
    return right; // Could make a deep copy.
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It's still giving me the StackOverflowError, though. I think the problem lies in the tail(). If I can somehow get the tail() working without having to use the head(), it might work out. :-(

Comment: I have added the logical tail implementation. _(Always the last method implemented evidently gets messed up.)_